# What is the difference between ledger_hash and ledger_index in Ripple?

Tags: ripple, api, json-rpc, standard, ledger-hardware-wallet

In rippled's API, for example in [`account_info`](https://ripple.com/wiki/JSON_Messages#account_info), we can see that `ledger_hash` and `ledger_index` are different from one another. [`ledger_hash`](https://ripple.com/wiki/JSON_API#ledger) is just a hash of the ledger. However, [in this graphic](https://ripple.com/wiki/File%3aLedger_entry.png) we can see that `ledger_index` also looks like a hash of the ledger. There doesn't appear to be [an entry for `ledger_index`](https://ripple.com/wiki/JSON_API#ledger_index) in the Wiki, so what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ledger_index` is the 256-bit index of a particular entry in the ledger. The ledger's state tree is a hash tree of index/value pairs. Each index is a 256-bit hash of some kind of locator. If the entry is, say, an account root node, the index is a hash of the 160-bit account ID. If the entry is, say, a ripple balance node, the index is a hash of the two accounts the balance is between and the currency identifier.

The `ledger_hash` is the 256-bit hash of the ledger header, which effectively acts as a hash of the entire ledger.